# Making a Game in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, game-engine

This doesn't really have to just be in JavaScript but in all Languages where games can be made. I just don't get it. I just don't get how something like:

```
B.Gd = function () {
    var a = this.na,
        b = this.Hb(),
        c = this.ba || 1,
        d = c / a,
        e;
    if (this.b) {
        this.xb && this.xb.contains(b) && (e = Ka(this.xb.size()) / Ka(b.size())) && 1.6 > e && 0.5 < e ? b = this.xb : 1 != this.He && 0 != this.g.length && (this instanceof C || b.expand(12, 12, 12, 12));
        this.xb = b;
        var f = b.size();
        e = f.e()
            .scale(c)
            .ceil();
        if (this.b.width != e.width || this.b.height != e.height) this.b.width = e.width, this.b.height = e.height, this.Lb = 1;
        var g = this.C.e();
        this.m[D] && (g = this.m[D]);
        0 != e.width ? g.scale(f.width * d / e.width) : g.scale(1 / a);
        a = E(this);
        this.Vb = (a.left - b.left) * c;
        this.Wb = (a.top - b.top) * c;
        b = this.f()
            .e();
        a = this.Y;
        b.width *= a.x;
        b.height *= a.y;
        b = b.scale(c);
        c = this.d.e();
        this.m[F] && (c = this.m[F]);
        c.x *= d;
        c.y *= d;
        c.x -= b.width + this.Vb;
        c.y -= b.height + this.Wb;
        Oa(this.b, 100 * ((this.Vb + b.width) / e.width), 100 * ((this.Wb + b.height) / e.height), k);
        !this.T[F] && (!this.T[D] && !this.T[Pa]) && (d = -(this.J %= 360), s(this.m[Pa]) && (d = -this.m[Pa]), Qa(this.b, Ra(new Sa, 0.1)
            .translate(c.x, c.y)
            .scale(g.x, g.y)
            .rotate(d)));
        this.Lb && (d = this.b.getContext("2d"), c = this.ba || 1, d.clearRect(0,
        0, e.width, e.height), d.save(), d.translate(this.Vb, this.Wb), d.scale(c, c), e = this.f(), g = this.Y, d.translate(e.width * g.x, e.height * g.y), this.q.Zc.call(this, d), d.restore(), this.Lb = 0)
    }
};
```

In the end will come out to be a game. I'm always amazed when I look at source codes of games such as this one: "http://www.limejs.com/static/zlizer/index.html" which is where I got that little snippet of code from (http://www.limejs.com/static/zlizer/zlizer.js). I just want to know, can anyone make sense of this? Can anyone explain to me how people write this kinda stuff? If I were to make a game I wouldn't know how to start. Or end.

This is more a question for people who actually have made a game that required Math like the one above.

How do you guys do it? It's so amazing and it seems so difficult. I'm not planning on making a game, this is just a question I was wondering and I wanted some kind of answer.

Comment: "Time and directed application of effort/thinking". Isn't that all programming is? (Anyway: Not Constructive)

Comment: I'd start by opening a programming book? ;)

Answer (score 3):

This code is likely not that complicated. I would assume the code has gone through [obfuscation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code). The author doesn't want you to read it.